# MYSQL query with partial match

Tags: mysql

I have this query which is working fine :

```
search = str(1)
"SELECT * FROM table_contacts WHERE id RLIKE %s", [search]
```

But I would like to compare `id` to some column on my database in this format :

```
;1;
```

I tried  :

```
search = (";"+str(column_value)+";")
"SELECT * FROM table_contacts WHERE id RLIKE %s", [search]
```

Where `column_value` is an INTEGER that returns 1 but it returns nothing.

I was expected the query to find the `1` in the sequence `;1;` since I used RLIKE.

Can someone help me on this one ? Thanks

Comment: change **search = (";"+str(column_value)+";")** to **search = ("%;"+str(column_value)+";%")** and RLIKE TO LIKE

Comment: Also of note REGEX is really useful to test patterns,  especially when you have a known format such as #:#:#:#

Comment: use **;?5;?** as regex . the ? after the ; means 0 or one time this char